# Setting the file name for exporting from a temporary buffer

Tags: org-export

Consider:

```el
(defun my-export-to-file (orig-fun &rest args)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (org-mode)
    (insert "some contents")
    (rename-buffer "mybuffer.org" t)
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'org-export-to-file :around #'my-export-to-file)
```

When I run export from the currently active buffer, the name is derived from that buffer instead of being `mybuffer.org`. Why is this the case and how do I set the file name for exporting from the temporary buffer?

Comment: Org export uses `buffer-file-name`, not `(buffer-name)`, to determine the name of the buffer. You can either use `set-visited-file-name` instead of `rename-buffer` or set the Org keyword `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` in your buffer/subtree.

Comment: @Basil The documentation (https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) says about `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME`: "The name of the output file to be generated. Otherwise, Org generates the file name based on the buffer name and the extension based on the back-end format," which sounds like `buffer-name` is used. Also, what does it do when `(buffer-file-name)` is nil, e.g. in scratch or temporary buffer?

Comment: The documentation should be clarified then, just look for yourself: https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/ox.el#L6309-L6327. Judging from a quick glance at the code, it looks like when the buffer has no `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` keyword and is not associated with a file, Org will prompt the user.

Comment: @Basil Then why doesn't it prompt in the example in my question?

Comment: I can't tell unless you provide more information, i.e. a full recipe of how you end up with this behaviour. Nevertheless, I see that the second argument to `org-export-to-file` specifies the export file, so why don't you just pass your preferred file there instead of calling `rename-buffer`?

Comment: @Basil With the example code, I call `org-export-dispatch` and then press `lp` to export into `LaTeX` following `PDF`, but the export format could be anything in practice. I want to avoid computing the file name for export myself if I can rely on `org-export` facilities to do it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that `org-export-to-file` accepted the final exported filename as second argument. Doesn't that make your whole `:around` advice moot, since the `args` passed to `orig-fun` will already contain the final, computed export filename? You probably need to inject your preferred filename somewhere earlier in the call chain, or just use `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` and be done with it.

Comment: @Basil Makes sense! This explanation should become a reply.